# ASP.NET adding unwanted padding to div

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am getting an unwanted `style="padding:10px;"` added to an ASP.NET content div.

The generated HTML for the div tag is:

```
<div id="ctl00_oMasterContentDiv" class="SCMainContent" style="padding:10px;">
```

The definition in the master file is:

```
<div class="SCMainContent" runat="server" id="oMasterContentDiv">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="oCPH1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Attempting to add `style="padding: 0px;"` to the div definition results in that attribute being removed and overwritten.

What would or could cause this behavior?

Comment: There must be something in your code adding the style. I can't see how or why ASP.Net would add padding by default.

Comment: ^This. Look in your code behind file for "oMasterContentDiv". There should be something that's adding the padding.

Comment: why are people answering with `!important`? there has to be a reason this is being added than fixing it with a patch.

Comment: @f0x CSS people doesn't know about ASP part so ...

Comment: @f0x Answers are not wrong either

Comment: Liam and jfrej had it. There was something buried in the code-behind.

If one of you were to submit that as an answer of some sort, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something in your code adding the style. I can't see how or why ASP.Net would add padding by default.